# UIButton in UIBarButtonItem not showing up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have the following in my view did load on my table view controller:

```
UIButton *change_view = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[change_view setTitle:@"List" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[change_view addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: change_view];    
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

When I run the program, it doesn't show any title or the rounded rectangle button. However, if I change the type to UIButtonTypeInfoLight, it will show up... so what is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set an appropriate frame to your `change_view`.

When you use `UIButtonTypeInfoLight` type button uses some built-in size (likely depended on icon used for it), with `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` type default frame is applied which must be `CGRectZero` rect.

Comment: how do you set the frame of a button?

Comment: change_view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height), with appropriate width and height. If you use different strings for a title (e.g. localizing it) you may need to calculate the width dynamically...

Answer (score 16):

I'd prefer the way below to set the button's bounds.

```
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button sizeToFit];
```